# oracle account lockout status

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-ebs

Did Oracle EBS has a feature to sent an email at the pre-registered email address if his or her **account is locked** ?

Does oracle EBS application **prevent information disclosure** about account lockout status sent to the user via the application interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said: "Did Oracle EBS has a feature to sent an email at the pre-registered email address ". Do you mean workflow notification mailer?

The EBS is managed using apps user.  If apps user is locked  then the whole EBS would be down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i mean for a normal application user. lets say the hrms manager application user....if his account is locked out due to multiple trials did he get that notification to his registered user email.... or he dont get that information or notification.

Comment: I have created one user on my test environment to test this:
I created one user and made it my supervisor (meaning, that user would be notified with any request i do).  I tried to do requests for both cases : (before locking that account out and after locking that account out) and checked the work list for any notification. Guess what!The both requests were displayed to that user after their account  was back active again.So, i think the same will happen to their Email.It will be queued till released when the user get active.  I am not sure about the last part but you can test the email part.

Comment: I don't have test environment for any Email service.  otherwise, would have tested that out for you. 
Let me know what  the observations would be when you test that out.